# PDF has all the page edges cropped - how can I view the full pages?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I have a PDF which I need to create a JPG image of the first page. Normally I'd just load the PDF to Photoshop, or there are online services (pdf2jpg) I could normally do this through as well.

However, this PDF appears to have had all the page edges cropped, I can't see the full pages? In Photoshop, if I extract individual images, the entire images are still there, but I can't figure out how to get the full pages themselves. Is there some property to this PDF that is causing this - is there any way to fix it? Is this some standard method of publishing, and I need some more specific software? Or is the PDF itself missing the required info to view the full pages?

I've dropped a copy of the PDF here:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pectvel4lqwacc3/AACtb7ZDJwYinVoloeroEclva?dl=0

I've never seen anything like this before, and after much searching and messing around, can't seem to find any additional info, or any method that lets me see the pages all the way to the edges.

Comment: The PDF appears to be corrupted or improperly created.  Some PDF utilities won't even open the document.  The viewers that do show the cropping.  If you have access to the source document, you could recreate the PDF.  If you are able to open the individual images, you could build a new document from them.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks so much for the analysis, I thought maybe I was just missing something, sounds like this is corrupted somehow. I don't have access to the source, and I'm not sure what they've done, and the sender unfortunately isn't technical. I have a printed physical copy, which is fine, so there must be a good original somewhere. I'll have to see what else I can find out, if I find anything of note I'll post it back here - still not sure how someone has managed to do this!